# How do I interact with bash command line?

Tags: databricks

I want to install miniconda in databricks environment
I run the following code:

```
%sh
/dbfs/FileStore/Miniconda3_latest_Linux_x86_64.sh
```

But I can't interact with command line, when it asks me to press Enter.

How do I pass Enter in databricks notebook ?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to just press Enter?

Comment: yes, when I press enter inside notebook. It just doesn't interact with command, it works like if I would edit notebook.

Comment: and I cannot press enter clicking on the command, as it doesn't accept any interactions with it

Comment: It asks to review some license agreement.. maybe you need to scroll down and pass through that license, first.

Comment: I cannot scroll down or do anything with this command, it simply doesn't let me interact with it. I click multiple times on the running command/terminal and it simply doesn't let me interact

Comment: why do you need to install conda? It should be already there, especially if you select ML runtime...

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing Miniconda in [silent mode](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/silent-mode/#linux-macos), which will not prompt you to press any keys to accept the license, etc.

```
%sh
/dbfs/FileStore/Miniconda3_latest_Linux_x86_64.sh -b
```

You'll need to follow the other instructions in the link in order to set up the conda environment properly. Maybe something like

```
%sh
eval "$(/path/to/miniconda/bin/conda shell.bash hook)"
conda init
```